# How can I prevent bbdb from asking me to add emails in gnus?

Tags: gnus, bbdb

How can I prevent bbdb from asking me:

```
"%s is not in BBDB; add? (y,!,s,u,n,q,?) "
```

for every mail I read?;)

What I want instead is to ignore these addresses.

I've tried:

```
(setq bbdb-message-pop-up nil)
(setq bbdb-mua-pop-up nil)
(setq bbdb-completion-display-record nil)
```

My version is

```
Version: 3.2.2d
```

Comment: You need to specify the version of BBDB you are using.

Comment: Then do `M-x locate-library RET bbdb.el RET`, visit the file and copy the version info from the commentary at the top of the file. Also, if you don't want to be asked about non-existing addresses, what do you want to do with them? Add them automatically?  Ignore them? Something else?

Comment: ok, that says Version: 3.2.2d . I want to ignore. I have like 500 mailing-lists and it asks me whenever I open any mail from any of them;)

Comment: You should probably try to figure out why `M-x bbdb-version` says `unknown` and try to fix it.

Comment: Actually, I am a bit confused: 3.2.2d asks the question in this format: `"%s is not in BBDB; add? (y,!,s,u,n,q,?) "` - note the lower-case *add* and the various options. But you mention an upper-case *Add* and no options, which might have been the format in an earlier version. Maybe you have two (or more) versions installed somewhere and they are tripping over each other?

Comment: You're right. I was not able to copy this text from the Echo Area and it was not appearing in the Messages buffer. I've updated the question;). Btw, how would I copy or log what appears in the Echo Area?

Comment: This is done with `(read-key-sequence PROMPT)` and AFAICT, the PROMPT is not saved anywhere where you can cut/copy-and-paste: you need to carefully type it one character at a time in another window so as not to disturb the echo area in Emacs (e.g. in a terminal window) in order to report it accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Customize `bbdb-mua-action` and set it to nil. You'll probably want to check the doc string with `C-h v bbdb-mua-action` and perhaps pick something else (maybe `update` - or maybe define your own function to do whatever you want).

The choices are:

```
Allowed values are (here ADDRESS is an email address selected
by ‘bbdb-select-message’):
 nil          Do nothing.
 search       Search for existing records matching ADDRESS.
 update       Search for existing records matching ADDRESS;
                update name and mail field if necessary.
 query        Search for existing records matching ADDRESS;
                query for creation of a new record if the record does not exist.
 create or t  Search for existing records matching ADDRESS;
                create a new record if it does not yet exist.
 a function   This functions will be called with no arguments.
                It should return one of the above values.
```

I've tested it with `create` which creates a new entry automatically, but not with any other value, but I think it should work.

EDIT: in earlier versions, `bbdb-mua-action` was called `bbdb-update-records-p` which is now an obsolete alias - but if you are using an earlier version (see my comment below your question for caveats), you might have to customize the older variable if the new one does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick; this is not working;) It's still asking me.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine: I customize the variable and set it to `query`, apply the settings and I'm getting the question; I customize it again and set it to `do nothing` and there are no questions (and no additions); I customize it again and set it to `create` (or as the customize interface has it: "annotate all messages") and I get the entry added if it's not there already, no questions asked. Make sure that the only installation of `bbdb` you have is the expected one. Make sure that the version is 3.2.2d. Check the value with `C-h v bbdb-mua-action`...

Comment: ... and *also* `C-h v bbdb-update-records-p` just in case you are using some older version (see the final paragraph in my answer). If those two are different, there is something wrong. Check if you are shadowing the library with `M-x list-load-path-shadows`: that should be empty in general, but if it's not you should really make sure to understand *why* it is not empty.

Comment: ... and update your question with your findings, so that they are not lost in comments.